# How to know the apk version before installing it?

Tags: apk, adb, version

I have to scan the apk version before installing it using adb.

Is there an adb command which allow to know the version of an apk stored on my hard disk before installing it ?

I tried to see different adb command and i saw `adb shell pm list packages`

But it worked with a device not on the apk stored on my hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it using cmd.

SDK> build-tools>select any directory(use latest version)> open cmd here and type following line and hit enter

```
D:\SDK\build-tools\28.0.3> aapt dump badging apkname.apk
```

above command will gives you **package name, VersionCode,VersionName** and may more information

i have copied my apk in same location i.e in 28.0.3